# Qualitative properties of ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems

I want to show that all solutions of the system
$$
\dot{x} = y, \quad \dot{y} = \frac{4}{x^5}
$$
(phase space $\mathbb{R} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace \times \mathbb{R}$) exist on $\mathbb{R}$.

So far I found that the expression
$$
\frac{1}{2}y^2(t) + \frac{1}{x^4(t)}
$$
is constant for all solutions $x, y$ meaning that $\lvert y (t) \rvert$ is bounded from above and $\lvert x(t) \rvert$ is bounded from below...

How can I proceed from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that there is $t_0>0$ such that
$$ \lim_{t\to t_0^-} x(t)=\infty. $$
Namely,
$$ x(t) \text{ is not left continuous at $t=t_0$.} \tag{*} $$
Letting $t\to t_0^-$ in
$$ \frac{1}{2}y^2(t) + \frac{1}{x^4(t)} = C$$
gives
$$ y^2(t_0)=2C. $$
So $x'(t_0)=y(t_0)$ is finite and hence $x(t)$ is continuous at $t=t_0$, which is against (*).